# R: Getting Last word/phrase which is non uniform

Tags: r, string

I have a column within a data frame that has a bunch of words.  The last word is what I want to extract, but it is non uniform.  Example:

Other4 00:15:21 RUN 1

Other5 00:50:20 RUN2

Other1 12:15:23 Run 3

Other2 17:18:19 run4

How would I go about getting the last word/phrase which is the word "run" and the number which may or may not be separated by space?

I've tried     strsplit

```
do.call(rbind,
lapply(
strsplit(x," "),
function(y)
cbind(paste(head(y,length(y)-1),collapse=" "),tail(y,1))
)
)
```

But it will only return the last word/number

Comment: Is the text preceding the targeted word always the same length? OR does it have the same number of spaces?

Comment: @SprengMeister No, it can vary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
v1 <- c("Other4 00:15:21 RUN 1","Other5 00:50:20 RUN2","Other1 12:15:23 Run 3","Other2 17:18:19 run4")

library(stringr)
str_extract(v1, perl('(?<=:\\d{2} )[ A-Za-z0-9]+$'))
[1] "RUN 1" "RUN2"  "Run 3" "run4"
```

#### Explanation

Assuming that after the `:` you have only two digits, the regex `(?<=:\\d{2} )` lookbehind for `:` followed by two `digits` and a `space`. Extracts the digits, characters following the match.

Or

```
 library(stringi)
 stri_extract_last(v1, regex="[A-Za-z]+ ?\\d+")
 #[1] "RUN 1" "RUN2"  "Run 3" "run4"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
> z <- c("Other4 00:15:21 RUN 1", "Other5 00:50:20 RUN2",
         "Other1 12:15:23 Run 3", "Other2 17:18:19 run4", NULL, "hello")
> pattern <- '.*?(\\w+ *\\d+)$'
> gsub(pattern, '\\1', grep(pattern, z, ignore.case=T, value=T), ignore.case=T)
[1] "RUN 1" "RUN2"  "Run 3" "run4"
```

In the pattern, we capture 1 or more word characters followed by 0 or more spaces and 1 or more digits, anchored to the end. We match the text before the captured group `(...)` using non-greedy matching `.*?`.

The `grep` inside filters the content of the vector, the `gsub` outside extracts the relevant part.

Comment: What does the \\1 within gsub do?

Comment: It refers to "capture group 1" -- the pattern matched within the `(...)`